# SQLite Database - No Such Table (SQLiteException)

Tags: java, android, mysql, sqlite

First off I would just like to say I have read through most(if not all) of the other topics regarding this same issue and have tried as many solutions as I can but too no avail.

I am trying to create an SQLDatabase with 3 Tables. The First table and it's associated methods all work fine(insertData, getAllData, deleteRow). However the second table is where the problem lies, whenever I try to insert a row it throws the "No Such Table Exception".

Below is the code for Creating my Tables

```
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Information";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;

    //Allergy Table
    private static final String TABLE_NAME_A = "AllergyTable";
    private static final String NAME = "Allergy";
    private static final String UIDA = "_id";
    private static final String CREATE_TABLE_A = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME_A + "(" + UIDA + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + NAME + " VARCHAR(255));";
    private static final String DROP_TABLE_A = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME_A;


    //Medication Table
    private static final String TABLE_NAME_M = "MedicationsTable";
    private static final String MEDICATION = "Medication";
    private static final String DOSAGE = "Dosage";
    private static final String UIDM = "_id";
    private static final String CREATE_TABLE_M = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME_M + "(" + UIDM + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + MEDICATION + " VARCHAR(255)), " + DOSAGE + " VARCHAR(255));";
    private static final String DROP_TABLE_M = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME_M;

    //Conditions Table
    private static final String TABLE_NAME_C = "ConditionsTable";
    private static final String CONDITION = "Condition";
    private static final String INFO = "Info";
    private static final String UIDC = "_id";
    private static final String CREATE_TABLE_C = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME_C + "(" + UIDC + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + CONDITION + " VARCHAR(255)), " + INFO + " VARCHAR(255));";
    private static final String DROP_TABLE_C = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME_C;
```

These are my onCreate and onUpgrade methods:

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        try {
            db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_A);
            db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_M);
            db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_C);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        try {
            db.execSQL(DROP_TABLE_A);
            db.execSQL(DROP_TABLE_M);
            db.execSQL(DROP_TABLE_C);
            onCreate(db);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

This is the insert method I am using:

```
//Medication Table
public long insertDataMeds(String meds, String dosage) {
    if(meds.length() > 0) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = sqlHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(sqlHelper.MEDICATION, meds);
        cv.put(sqlHelper.DOSAGE, dosage);
        long id = db.insert(sqlHelper.TABLE_NAME_M, null, cv);
        return id;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

The Following mess is my LogCat file.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: MedicationsTable (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT Medication, Dosage FROM MedicationsTable
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:882)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:493)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1314)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1161)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1032)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1200)
at com.medinfo.database.SQLDataBaseAdapter.getAllDataMeds(SQLDataBaseAdapter.java:73)
at com.medinfo.main.EditMedication.onClick(EditMedication.java:46)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I have tried running the app on both an emulator and a physical device, I have tried a clean rebuild of the app, I have also uninstalled and reinstalled the app. I have also incremented the database version number. Nothing seems to work. and I have no idea why the first table and it's methods are all working as they should be.

Comment: You've got an extra `)` in the `+ " VARCHAR(255)), " + ` part of the CREATE statement. In the last table's CREATE statement, too.

Comment: Wow, I feel like a complete moron for missing such a simple thing. Thank you for pointing that out, I really appreciate it. I should not be coding so late at night it seems :/.

Comment: You shouldn't have `try`-`catch` in your `onCreate()` and `onUpgrade()` - that only hides any problems there.

Comment: Oh okay that is interesting. I shall remove those try catch loops then :). Thank you.